# How do I sort this file?

Tags: python, sorting

So I'm trying to sort a file alphabetically. I have a text file zoznam.txt which contains names. When I run my code, it sorts them, but it doesn't write each name in a new line, it writes them in the same line. Please help me. I know how to do it in print output, but I need it to make a new text file with names sorted.

```
with open("zoznam.txt") as file:
    content = file.readlines()

output = open("zoznam(sorted).txt", "w")

content = sorted(content)

for i in content:
    output.write(i.replace("\n", ""))

output.close()
```

Comment: You replaced "\n" with "" that's why it's not writing to new lines, just get rid of the `replace`.

Comment: `output.writelines(content)`. No need of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are using `i.replace("\n", "")`: basically, it remove lines return